# Best way to take backup of Mysql Database on Shared Hosting

Tags: mysql, database

I am facing issue while importing mysql database for backup thru cpanel as the database size is around 400MB.

Can anybody guide me how to take mysql database backup as I am using shared hosting and cpanel method is not working for backup.

Thanks